# Is there a way to rewrite my urls without using mod_rewrite and .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there a way to rewrite my urls from:

http://www.website.com/notification.php

to

http://www.website.com/notification

I dont have the permission to turn on mod_rewrite and our organisation doesnt want it either. Is there a way to realise this with php only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure if you dont mind urls like `/index.php/notification`

Comment: There're pure-PHP routers (e.g. [nikic/fast-route](https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/fast-route)). However, without `mod_rewrite` it isn't trivial to completely hide the routing script itself so you'd end up with stuff like `http://example.com/index.php?/foo/bar` or maybe `http://example.com/index/foo/bar` depending on the Apache settings you're allowed to use; plus you need to write your code on top of the routing facility, which may only be feasible in new projects. `mod_rewrite` is a fairly basic tool anyway so I can figure out the overall quality of the organisation projects ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the  reply... My  client give me an access SSh to confingure the apache.. But when i enable the  mode rewrite and  add the  Alloverride All  to the  directory on my  virtuellehost i had an error 500 a misconfigure  server any idea ? After i added thé .htacess on the project  directory

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" just means the server is configured to not display error messages. You need to look for the in the server logs.

Comment: in the server logs i get configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: / any ideas ?

Comment: Well, `AuthType` has of course nothing to do with `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a few pages, you could rename your files `index.php` and move it inside directories with your desired name.

So `notification.php` becomes `notification/index.php` and you could access it with the url `/notification` or `/notification/`.

Downside of this method is, you get a messy folder structure and every file is named index.php. You could come around the later issue, if you put some kind of wrapper file inside each folder, which calls the actual script - but the folder structure stays the same.

---

An other way would be to use some kind of pseudo rewrites with urls starting with `?`. So you could call access your files like `website.com/?notification`. In this case, you have to put all your routing logic inside an `index.php` located at `/`. The good part about this is, that your urls stay flexible and you don't have to create some strange file system structure. Bad point is, you have to keep the question mark in each url.

Comment: Can you answer the the question? `/notification.php` into `/notification` if not then the answer should be **no** its not possible. Not a work around, thats obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... My client give me an access SSh to confingure the apache.. But when i enable the mode rewrite and add the Alloverride All to the directory on my virtuellehost i had an error 500 a misconfigure server any idea ? After i added thé .htacess on the project directory..

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduce [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

> pushState() takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is
>   currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL.

**Example :-**

URL :- http://www.website.com/notification.php

```
window.history.pushState('notification.php', 'Title', 'notification');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you can do this "simply":

```
<Location "/notification">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Location>
```

If you do this I hope you're using a flexible request router as you'll be using REQUEST_URI *a lot*. As apache won't bother looking for files or anything else AFAIK, so you'll have to return static resources (images, stylesheets, js, etc) yourself.

Regardless, it seems like you can use this in a .htaccess file so you don't need to bother the server's main configuration.

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler

Comment: Thank you for the reply... My client give me an access SSh to confingure the apache.. But when i enable the mode rewrite and add the Alloverride All to the directory on my virtuellehost i had an error 500 a misconfigure server any idea ? After i added thé .htacess on the project directory